# Как создать массив из схожих ключей с индексами в квадратных скобках?

Tags: php

В post-запросе приходит примерно следующее:

```
[question-preptime-2] => 110
[question-anstime-2] => 33
[question-subquest-2[1]] => cv
[question-subquest-2[2]] => sdf
[question-subquest-2[3]] => sdfsd
[question-subquest-2[4]] => 345dh
```

Как из ключей содержащих **question-subquest** создать отдельный массив, где ключ будет цифра в квадратных сбоках, т.е. в итоге получить:

```
[question-subquest-2] => Array
        (            
            [1] => cv
            [2] => sdf
            [3] => sdfsd
            [4] => 345dh
        )
```

Comment: Правильнее будет такой ужас не присылать, а делать сразу нормально

Comment: Согласен, но кто-то ранее уже сделал такой ужас, поэтому надо разбираться. А как и где это реализовано искать сложно, там дикие велосипеды

Comment: Может всё же стОит воспользоваться советом дядюшки Мартина и "Оставить место стоянки чище, чем оно было до твоего прихода." ?))

Answer (score 0):

Само собой `$post` поменять на `$_POST`.

```php
<?php
$post = [ 'question-preptime-2' => 110,
          'question-anstime-2' => 33,
          'question-subquest-2[1]' => 'cv',
          'question-subquest-2[2]' => 'sdf',
          'question-subquest-2[3]' => 'sdfsd',
          'question-subquest-2[4]' => '345dh'
        ];

$outArray = [];

foreach( $post as $key => $value ) {
    preg_match_all("/(\S+)\[(\d+)\]$/", $key, $matches);
    if ( is_array( $matches ) && count( $matches ) >= 3 && is_array( $matches[1] ) && count( $matches[1] ) > 0 && is_array( $matches[2] ) && count( $matches[2] ) > 0 ) {
        if ( !isset( $outArray[ trim( $matches[1][0] ) ] ) )  {
            $outArray[ trim( $matches[1][0] ) ] = [];
        } 
        $outArray[ trim( $matches[1][0] ) ][ trim( $matches[2][0] ) ] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump( $outArray );
```

Результат:

```
array(1) {'question-subquest-2' => array(4) { [1] => "cv",
                                              [2] => "sdf",
                                              [3] => "sdfsd",
                                              [4] => "345dh"
                                            }
}
```